# Image src is wrong in subdirectory

Tags: wordpress

I moved a WordPress site from root directory 'www.example.com' to 'www.example.com/test'. All items as CSS files, js files, and etc full loaded and work currently but images are not working. src of images has not '/test/' in the address.

Currently, this figure is

```
src="http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/stiky-75x75.png"
```

But should this be

```
src="http://www.example.com/test/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/stiky-75x75.png"
```

I try with .htaccess, create that one and insert a rewrite rule but do nothing to me.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How is the `src` being called in the template? Can we see the relevant template code? You shouldn't need to modify **.htaccess** if you're calling the images properly.

Comment: IIRC you can set an `uploadpath` somewhere in the settings.

Comment: @IkoTikashi, the OP shouldn't need to do this. The new upload directory should already default to `http://www.example.com/test/wp-content/uploads/`

Comment: Ok, been a while since I used WP. @OP: have you read http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress ??

Comment: All images in my site didn't show, for example post images. Yes, I read it, but doesn't help me.